# How do I stop this from going out of bounds, and why isn't what I'm already doing working?

Tags: java, arrays, swap, indexoutofboundsexception

```
string o = "meow"

public static void swapPairs(String o){
    char x;
    char y;
    char[] oc = o.toCharArray();

    //Array goes out of bounds, but it still works. 
    for(int i = 0; i<= oc.length+2;i=i+2){
        x=oc[i];
        oc[i]=oc[i+1];
        oc[i+1]=x;  

        System.out.println(oc[i]+"\n"+oc[i+1]);      
    }
}
```

The goal of this method is to swap every two characters in a string, I searched and I couldn't understand the other solutions.   This method works with the word meow, but it still goes out of bounds. Why?
**If Google Sent you here**: I was adding two to the end of the array instead of removing two.  simple mistakes always sneak up on me.

**Edit:  Now i've run into a problem with uneven strings.   How do I tell the compiler to just leave the last character if there isn't a match?**

Comment: `it still goes out of bounds. Why?` because you are trying to access element whose index is greater than the length of the array itself thats why.

Comment: `i <= oc.length + 2` This will always cause issues. The maximum length is length, you loop until length + 2.

Comment: Dude.  Do the math.  "meow" is of length 4.  Your for loop is moving i from 0 to oc.length+2 which is 6 for "meow".  Of course you are going out of bounds!  Your story is going to be pretty bad if you start with "" or an odd number as well.  You need to factor your whole solution differently.  Think in terms of how many pairs there can be and work out from there.

Comment: I'm still foggy on how arrays work, I didn't realize that it would go over.   I thought the extra two would compensate.  Sorry.  @BobKuhar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oc.length` will return the length of the `oc` array.

Arrays are 0-indexed, which means the last element in the array will be `oc.length-1`.

`i<=oc.length+2` means your loop will continue until `i` is 3 past the last index.  But also, in the loop, you're trying to access index `i+1` which if the program let you, would go all the way out to the **FOURTH** index past the last index.

Given that you're trying to access `oc[i+1]`, you need to change your `for` loop to look more like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<oc.length-1; i=i+2)
```

Please note, that's `<`, and not `<=`.

---

To print it, if you want it all on one line, you can just do this after the loop:

```
System.out.println(new String(oc));
```

---

One other note, that may have helped you understand the problem more completely before posting to StackOverflow, if you're writing in Eclipse (and maybe some of the other programs), the stacktrace would have told you more than just OBE.  It's great that you at least read that and could narrow down the posted code to exactly where the error was occurring, but if you pay close enough attention, that stacktrace will usually tell you the number of the index that was attempted to be accessed, and it will tell you the number of the last available index in the array.

Comment: Thanks! But how do i make the compiler leave uneven remaining characters alone?

Comment: If your word is `maths`, you'll start at index 0, `m`, and swap `0` and `1`, leaving you with `amths`.  Then you'll add two to `i` and do it again.  You'll be on index 2, `t`, and swap `2` and `3`, leaving you with `amhts`.  Now you'll add `2` to index, and be on index `4`.  When `i<oc.length-2` is evaluated for `4`, it will return false in this case, and it won't try to do anything with the dangling `s`.  So the final result will be `amhts`.  Is this what you intend?  Is this what your question means?

Comment: It's not printing the last s.   Studying for finals has destroyed my brain... Do I just need to relocate the sys.out.print command?

Comment: Probably.  In your posted code, the `System.out.println` will actually complain because the `i` isn't in scope at all.  How exactly do you want the print to look?  You want each character on its own line?

Comment: Alright so thanks to your explanation I was able to make a solution that doesn't throw an OBE, but it won't print the last letter  if I use an uneven string.   I don't understand why.  on the final run through of the for loop, shouldn't it print the last value since I have both oc[i] and oc[i+1]?

Comment: Because in the example of `maths`, the final iteration of the loop deals with `th`, not `s` at all.  Are you wanting to print the whole word on a single line, or is it important for the word to be spaced out with a single character per line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42903/discussion-between-christopher-baldwin-and-nhgrif)

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop goes beyond the length of the string (when `i` is `oc.length` or greater) and you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception; to solve this you need to restrict `i` so that it is always less than `oc.length-1` (since you need each character and the successive character to swap).

You can do something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void swapPairs(final String o){
        char x;
        char[] oc = o.toCharArray();

        //Array goes out of bounds, but it still works. 
        for(int i = 0; i<oc.length-1;i=i+2){
            x=oc[i];
            oc[i]=oc[i+1];
            oc[i+1]=x;  
        }
        System.out.println(oc);      
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        swapPairs( "meow" );
        swapPairs( "meowe" );
    }
}
```

Comment: What??   I'm trying to swap characters using a single string.

Comment: It does not throw an out of bounds exception. If `i=oc.length-2` then `i+1` is `oc.length-1` which is not out of bounds.